# Parameters for request HttpGet aren't set

Tags: java, httpclient

I try to set parameters for request Get by

```
HttpGet.setParams method (new BasicHttpParams () .setParameter ("oauth_token", "Valid_token"))
```

to receive a request similar brought below:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/me?oauth_token=Valid_token
```

But when sending request by `HttpClient.execute (request)` method;

In logs shows that the **oauth_token** parameter wasn't added to request, prompt, in what a problem. When I inscribe the correct line in the browser everything works, in this case parameter simply isn't added to request

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I try to execute request which is similar to that is according to the link: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#me

Comment: What http client lib are you using?

Comment: @pomkine org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet

Comment: Where are you setting the request parameters? Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: @Perdomoff request.setParams(new BasicHttpParams().setParameter("oauth_token", userCredentials.getCredentials().getAccessToken()));       HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute( request_new );

Comment: you executing not the same request you created. request vs request_new

Comment: @pomkine Forgive, I was mistaken, there in a code "request" is written request.setParams(new BasicHttpParams().setParameter("oauth_token", userCredentials.getCredentials().getAccessToken())); HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute( request);

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it was necessary to set parameters not through the setParams method (), and obviously to set them in URI, how here https://api.soundcloud.com/me? me? oauth_token=A_VALID_TOKEN